# Ajax Delete gives 405 method not allowed after publish

Tags: ajax, json, api, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I try to remove a vehicles from the table .
This works well on the localhost (Visual Studio) after publishing, I get the message 405 method is not allowed.

```
http://localhost:41904/api/vehicles/42
```

after publish:

```
DELETE http://myurl.com/api/vehicles /42 405 Method Not Allowed
```

My ajax methode to delete:

```
      function reply_clic(clicked_id) {
      if (confirm("Systeem verwijderen?")) {
          $.ajax({
              url: '/api/' + clicked_id,  // RIS_POST_vehicle connected to button ID
              type: 'Delete',
              success: function (result) {
                  console.log('Joepie') // Do something with the result
                  $("#vehicleList").empty();
                  // bootbox.alert("Die is weg !!!");
                  loadvehicle()
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

The controller :

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Deletevehicle(int id)
    {
        vehicle vehicle = db.vehicle.Single(v => v.id_vehicle == id);
        if (vehicle == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.vehicle.DeleteObject(vehicle);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, vehicle);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be the first person to encounter this problem. StackOverflow has many questions (and answers) about it:

- [How can I enable DELETE verb in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127607/how-can-i-enable-delete-verb-in-iis7)
- [Why does HTTP DELETE verb return 405 error - method not allowed for my RESTful WCF service running on IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413455/why-does-http-delete-verb-return-405-error-method-not-allowed-for-my-restful-w)
- [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)
- [WebAPI Delete not working - 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619075/webapi-delete-not-working-405-method-not-allowed)
- ["405 method not allowed" in IIS7.5 for "PUT" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method)

Comment: thanks for this list! Unfortunately I have no solution. for 'PUT' You can also use Post in the controller, I was hoping for a solution in my controller..

Comment: Does "I have no solution" mean you have no administrative access to the IIS to reconfigure it?